# i can not use Unsplash

Tags: javascript, node.js

i try to use Unsplash for get images and want to use it in my app.
yes i created account in it and got application id and other credential and i try to use https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js in my code i try first

```
require('babel-register');
import Unsplash from 'unsplash-js';

const unsplash = new Unsplash({
 applicationId: ApplicationID,
 secret: Secret,
 callbackUrl: callbackUrl
});
```

first of all i face problem(error) after write this code

Error

```
import Unsplash from 'unsplash-js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Alex\photo\app.js:6:11)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

i got this error please give me solution.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use selected tag <option value="" selected>Never</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-init

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
 <select  ng-init="recureAdata='Never'" class="form-control" ng-model="recureAdata" id="recure" ng-change="recureidChange()">
    <option ng-value="0">Never</option>
    <option ng-value="1">Every One Week</option>
    <option ng-value="2">Every Two Week</option>
    <option ng-value="3">Every Three Week</option>
    <option ng-value="4">Every Four Week</option>
</select>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2RtOe0SVZx0zAURR0owl?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

In controller you have to assign the default selection value to your `ng-model="recureAdata"`

```
$scope.recureAdata=0
```

This code will help you to assign the default value to your `recureAdata` as

```
<option ng-value="0">Never</option>
```

Never will be your default selection value.You ca change it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

> In your directive you can set
>
> **scope.recureAdata = 0;**
>
> or In your controller
>
> **$scope.recureAdata = 0;**

Answer (score 1):

The best option for initializing select in `angular js` is to use `ng-options`. It provides the best way to initialise the select options by tracking the options with value. I have attached a sample code for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="changeExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="recureAdata" ng-options="Option.Value as Option.Name for Option in Options track by Option.Value" id="recure" ng-change="recureidChange()">
  
 </select>
        <script>
  var app = angular.module("changeExample", []);
  app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.Options = [{
    'Value': 0,
    'Name': 'Never'
    },
    {
    'Value': 1,
    'Name': 'Every One Week'
    },
    {
    'Value': 2,
    'Name': 'Every Two Week'
    },
    {
    'Value': 3,
    'Name': 'Every Three Week'
    },
    {
    'Value': 4,
    'Name': 'Every Four Week'
    }
                        ];
   $scope.recureAdata = $scope.Options[0];
  }]);
  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="recureAdata" id="recure" ng-change="recureidChange()">
 <option ng-value="0" ng-selected="true">Never</option>
 <option ng-value="1">Every One Week</option>
 <option ng-value="2">Every Two Week</option>
 <option ng-value="3">Every Three Week</option>
 <option ng-value="4">Every Four Week</option>
</select>
```